# Always display windows 10 notifications even when YouTube playing in background

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I use push notifications for very important things, but I've noticed that Windows doesn't always display the notification or play the notification sound when a notification comes in, which is hugely problematic. If I'm looking at the bottom right, a "1" will appear, but no noise and no popup.

This seems to happen when I'm playing a YouTube video (in the background, on a different windows virtual desktop).

I have "focus assist" disabled. If it's relevant, the notifications are coming from Chrome.

Comment: Have you verified that Focus Assist is off in the Action Center and also in *Settings > System > Focus assist* (all options)?

Comment: yes, it's "off", and I have all the automatic enable rules disabled, so it should never enable itself.

Comment: If using an NVIDIA graphic card, enable the "In-Game Overlay" in the settings for GeForce Experience. Otherwise, you will need to enable Focus Assist.